# Recursive definition of the error

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, error-function, rounding-error

Given the definition of

$I_n:=\frac{1}{e}\int_0^1 x^ne^x$
 for $n=0,1,2,...$

there is a recurrence relation:

$I_n=1-nI_{n-1}         $ 
  for $n=1,2,...$ and $I_0=\frac{e-1}{e}$

I've got to show that the recursive forrmula of the error (difference of the target value $I_n$ and the computed value $\tilde I_n$) is:

(1)   $    |\tilde I_n-I_n| \leq 3\epsilon+n(1+2\epsilon)|\tilde I_{n-1}-I_{n-1}|$,
where $\epsilon=\frac{fl(x)-x}{x}$.

Well I thoght of two ways that leads me to nowhere.
First way was:
I know that $\tilde I_n=fl(I_n)=fl(1-nI_{n-1})=1-nfl(I_{n-1})$.
so the absolute error would be $|I_n-fl(I_n)|=|1-nI_{n-1}-(1-nfl(I_{n-1}))|=n|fl(I_{n-1})-I_{n-1}|=n|\tilde I_{n-1}-I_{n-1}|$, which has to be false because it is not equal (1).

Second way was kind of thinking:

$\tilde I_n=\widetilde{1-nI_{n-1}}\stackrel{(*1)}{=}(1-(nI_{n-1})(1+\epsilon_1))(1+\epsilon_2)=1-\epsilon_1\epsilon_2nI_{n-1}-\epsilon_1nI_{n-1}-\epsilon_2nI_{n-1}-nI_{n-1}+\epsilon_2$

$\Rightarrow|\tilde I_n-I_n|=|\tilde I_n-(1-nI_{n-1})|=|-\epsilon_1\epsilon_2nI_{n-1}-\epsilon_1nI_{n-1}-\epsilon_2nI_{n-1}+\epsilon_2| \\
\le|-(\epsilon_1\epsilon_2+\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)nI_{n-1}+\epsilon_2| \stackrel{(*2)}{\le}|3\epsilon+\epsilon|=4\epsilon$

(*1) as there are two operations

(*2) as $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \le \epsilon \le 1$

and as $0\leq I_{n-1}\leq\frac{1}{n}$

but again I do'n't see how to come close to (1)...
Does anyone know it better?

Comment: *I've got to show that the recursive forrmula of the error...* The *error* of what?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Here the error is the absolute value of difference between the target value $I_n$ and the computed value $\tilde{I}_n$.

Comment: yes, that is aked

Comment: The number $3$ in your upper bound is odd as there are only $2$ operations pr. iteration- Moreover, your definition of $\epsilon$ should perhaps be weakened to $|\epsilon| \leq u$, where $u$ is the unit roundoff. Please confirm the number 3 and check the definition of $\epsilon$.

Comment: I've edited it (below in my post) and have tried it like you said. But I'm doing something totally wrong, Is my approach right?

Comment: Do you mean the upper bound $3\epsilon$ only refers to the error made by  the two operations, or is it the other term $n(1+2\epsilon)$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get the inequality you got. Maybe there's some additional assumption. Here is what I got.

We have
$$\tag{1}
\tilde{I}_n:=\mathrm{fl}(I_n)=[1-n\tilde{I}_{n-1}(1+\delta_1)](1+\delta_2), \quad |\delta_i|\leq\epsilon.
$$
So
$$
\begin{split}
\tilde{I}_n-I_n
&=
[1-n\tilde{I}_{n-1}(1+\delta_1)](1+\delta_2)-(1-nI_{n-1})
\\
&=
\delta_2-n(\tilde{I}_{n-1}-I_{n-1})-\delta_1n\tilde{I}_{n-1}
-\delta_2n\tilde{I}_{n-1}-\delta_1\delta_2n\tilde{I}_{n-1}
\end{split}
$$
and using (1) this gives
$$\tag{2}
|\tilde{I}_n-I_n|\leq\epsilon + n|\tilde{I}_{n-1}-I_{n-1}|+3n\epsilon|\tilde{I}_{n-1}|.
$$
Since $0\leq I_{n-1}<I_0<1$, we have
$$
|\tilde{I}_{n-1}|\leq|\tilde{I}_{n-1}-I_{n-1}|+|I_{n-1}|
\leq|\tilde{I}_{n-1}-I_{n-1}|+1.
$$
Plugging this to (2) results in
$$
|\tilde{I}_n-I_n|
\leq(1+3n)\epsilon+4n\epsilon|\tilde{I}_{n-1}-I_{n-1}|.
$$

It is not exactly same as what you have but both inequalities show the important fact that this way of computing $I_n$ amplifies the rounding errors so that
$$
|\tilde{I}_n-I_n|\leq O(n!)\epsilon|\tilde{I}_0-I_0|.
$$

Comment: thanks for sharing your ideas.